# Display the Selected Data With Jumbling

Tags: javascript, c#

This is my C# code for Jumbling the data.

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    ScrambleData("dsafdsfsd");
}

public static string ScrambleData(string data)
{
    //string BaseAddress = "http://localhost/";
    string BaseAddress = "http://abcd/"; //Calling by Computer Name.
    string uri = "ScramblerService/Scrambler?value=" + data;
    string CompleteRequestURL = BaseAddress + uri;

    HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(CompleteRequestURL);
    //webrequest.Method = "GET";

    webrequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    string result;

    using (WebResponse response = webrequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Java Script code for User selected Data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function disp()
    {
        var txtArea = document.getElementById('MainContent_TextArea1');
        var start = txtArea.selectionStart;
        var finish = txtArea.selectionEnd;
        var sel = txtArea.value.substring(start, finish);
        document.getElementById("MainContent_Textarea2").value = sel;   
    }
</script>

<div>
    <asp:TextBox id="TextArea1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="form-control" Height="300px"></asp:TextBox>
    <INPUT type="button" onclick= "disp()" visible="true" value="Show" class="btn btn-primary"/>&nbsp;
    <input id="Textarea2" runat="server" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Here I am trying to display the user selected data. While displaying the user selected data I need to jumble the words and has to display in Text area2. But I need to call this action through "Show" button Only. 
Any Help Please..???
Any Suggestions Please...???

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing an id of "MainContent_Textarea2" but you don't have any element with that ID.  You do, however, have one called "Textarea2", have you tried using that?

```
document.getElementById("Textarea2").value = sel;
```

Comment: I don't have any problem there. It is working perfectly. But the problem is here I need to call the Scramble function through "Show" button.